# Не получается создать alias из сценария

Tags: bash

Создал файлик со следующим содержимым:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias some='echo 2'
```

Дал ему права на выполнение и ничего не происходит по выполнению сценария (алиас не создается). Что я делаю не так? Версия bash - 4.3.46

Comment: Он запустил новый баш, создал в нём алиас и тут же вышел. А вы чего хотели?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, добавить алиас хотел. Каким образом я могу добавить алиас в текущий баш?

Comment: man bash. Конкретно тут можно просто написать `source a.sh`

Comment: Вообще обычно алиасы добавляют в `.bashrc`/`.bash_aliases`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо. source это то, что надо было

Comment: @alvoro, для файлов, запускаемых через source, shebang лучше удалять (он не имеет смысла), и сами файлы делать неисполняемыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

псеводнимы, переменные, функции — всё это свойства процесса оболочки. они передаются «по наследству» дочерним процессам, но дочерний процесс **никак не может повлиять** на свойства родительского процесса.

когда вы «запускаете» скрипт, создаётся новый (дочерний) экземпляр процесса оболочки, и после его завершения все **его** псевдонимы, переменные и функции безвозвратно теряются (ну, если только не сохранены, например, в файл).

---

для того же, чтобы команды из скрипта выполнялись **внутри** текущего процесса оболочки (без создания дочернего процесса), можно воспользоваться встроенной командой `source` (или её синонимом — `.`):

```
$ source скрипт
```

или

```
$ . скрипт
```

---

вообще обычно определения всех псевдонимов, переменных и функций, которые должны быть доступны в каждом *интерактивном* сеансе оболочки, помещают в файл `~/.bashrc`, который как раз и «вызывается» с помощью команды `source ~/.bashrc` в конце запуска нового *интерактивного* сеанса.