# Как обновить /.bashrc после выполнения скрипта

Tags: linux, bash

Как можно обновить/.bashrc после выполнения скрипта?

Сам скрипт

```
echo 'Name'
read commandName 

echo 'Command'
read command 


alas="alias ${commandName}='${command}'"

echo "${alas}" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "${alas}" >> /home/anton/Scripts/alias
```

Comment: `~/.bashrc` вы успешно «обновляете». можете точно так же и `/.bashrc` «обновлять», если прав достаточно. правда, непонятно зачем.

Comment: Ну, может не обновлять. мне нужно чтоб алиасы были доступны сразу после завершения скрипта

Comment: так это же совершенно другой вопрос. и на него давно уже [есть ответ на этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626217/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  как вы помните все свои ответы?)

Comment: @eri, не помню, конечно. поиск рулит. а данный вопрос, кстати, мне кажется, стоит закрыть не как дубликат, а как очень невнятно сформулированный: из комментария автора понятно, что нужно ему совершенно не то, что написано в вопросе. это даже если не учитывать пропущенные тильды как в заголовке, так и в первой фразе.

Comment: как дубликат закрыть полезней потому как если ктото сформулирует вопрос также криво, то сразу увидит ссылку на ответ.